# Android Studio: One Layout design is not showing layout preview

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm quite new in app designing, so this may be solved somewhere else. But I have been unable to find the answer.

I have an app with 3 activities. 2 of them work with no problem. The 3th one has worked till now, but when I have tried to modify it I have discovered 3 things:

- No blueprints are shown at Android Studio design view: [no blueprints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcvhF.jpg)
- Changes don't seem to refresh in the design view
- Unless I erase something needed (like a button), changes have no impact in the final result

I have tried googling around finding a solution. Also tried erasing different parts of the XML file to see if I have some problem with the coding. Nothing worked. No blueprints, no changes in the preview in Android Studio, and no changes in the emulator unless I erase something needed (in that case I got a compilation error and the app didn't work at all, which is logical).

The other activities work normal, so I am prone to think that there might be a coding problem in the XML file? But I have been unable to find it. If I don't touch it, the app works fine.

Here you have the code for the XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Test"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_test"
    tools:visibility="visible">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Lay_Top"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:minHeight="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Lay_Constraint"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Sub_Temas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:text="@string/action_Temas_Test"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/Mostrar_R"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxWidth="100dp"
                android:text="@string/action_Mostrar" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/Lay_Constraint"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/Botones_debajo"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Lay_Top"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Lay_Top">


            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scroll"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight=".90">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Lay_Preguntas"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight=".90"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Pregunta"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/action_Pregunta"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Lay_Respuestas"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/Lay_R_a"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/R_a"
                                android:layout_width="55dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                android:text="a)" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/Respuesta_a"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:gravity="start"
                                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:text="@string/Respuesta_a"
                                android:textAllCaps="false" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/Lay_R_b"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/R_b"
                                android:layout_width="55dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                android:text="b)" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/Respuesta_b"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:gravity="start"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:text="@string/Respuesta_b"
                                android:textAllCaps="false" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/Lay_R_c"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:visibility="visible">

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/R_c"
                                android:layout_width="55dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                android:text="c)" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/Respuesta_c"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:gravity="start"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:text="@string/Respuesta_c"
                                android:textAllCaps="false" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/Lay_R_d"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/R_d"
                                android:layout_width="55dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                android:text="d)" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/Respuesta_d"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:gravity="start"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                                android:text="@string/Respuesta_d"
                                android:textAllCaps="false"
                                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/R_d" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Botones_debajo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Lay_Constraint"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="7dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="498dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Botones_abajo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Lay_Preguntas"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="7dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="498dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Anterior"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                    android:text="@string/Anterior"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/FIN"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/mybutton2"
                    android:text="@string/FIN"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Siguiente"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                    android:text="@string/Siguiente"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Ultimo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Botones_abajo"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="563dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/N_Hechas"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/N_Hechas"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView16"
                    android:layout_width="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="/" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/N_Total"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/N_Total" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/banner_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

                app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4714690554501841/7558886048"

                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <!--Your commentapp:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4714690554501841/7558886048"-->
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK! As soon as I ask it here I discover why it didn't work: I was editing the wrong layout!

Comment: Stack Overflow does not wish to retain off-topic pages such as this because they are not likely to help future researchers.  Ypu can spare curators some work by removing this page yourself.